# Coordinates do not match/missing in rworldmap plot

Tags: r, mapping, geo, rworldmap

I am currently trying to plot some coordinates on a map in the rworldmap package.

From what I've seen looking it up, this should be relatively straightforward, however it is giving me trouble.

An example of my data can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1lqi.jpg)

To plot the map (I'm focusing on Eurasia), I've used:

```
library(rworldmap)
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-27.0, 174.0), ylim = c(17.5, 77.7), col = "grey",border = "darkgrey",  bg = "lightblue")
```

The next step is plotting my coordinates on the map as points. My data frame containing the coordinates is `Coordinate_AD_Clean`. I've done as follows:

```
points(Coordinate_AD_Clean$long, Coordinate_AD_Clean$lat, col = "red", pch = "+")
```

This is where it breaks down however as the resulting plot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqk2.jpg).
I know this is wrong as none of my coordinates are in the ocean, and there should be 116 points on the map (the number in my data frame) while there are many fewer on the plot.

I am unsure why I have incorrect and missing coordinates. The coordinates I have in my data frame are from google maps, which shouldn't be an issue since I tested 2 or 3 different coordinates I pulled from google maps at random and these were plotted to the map fine. Is the issue how the data is formatted within my data frame? I also have multiple duplicate coordinates, could this be an issue? I'm at a bit of a loss so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: Except 2 or 4 points, I see other points in the ocean. Are the other points roughly at places you would expect? If you have duplicate points, they should not be a problem because they will be plotted over one another.

Comment: The points on the plot that is generated are not where they are expected at all. However looking at the plot I could potentially see some kind of issue where all the points have been shifted to different points on the map. For instance, I have coordinates from Iceland, Spain, and Hungary and some of the points on the failed plot look like they could be shifted left to arrive at these places...

Comment: Have you figured it out? I haven't used `rworldmap` but if it uses projections, having differing projections between your points and map could make it to appear in unexpected places. If you could provide a sample coordinates for some points, it will be easier to provide an alternative solution. `dput(Coordinate_AD_Clean[1:15,])` is an easier way to provide sample data for reproducing the problem or to offer solutions.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but your suggestion actually did draw something to my attention. [this](https://pastebin.com/iBUve6vp) is a pastebin of the output I got from using `dput(Coordinate_AD_Clean[1:15:2],)` (Error message the first time saying I had undefined collumns). Interestingly, there are entries showing up (e.g '3.598°W') that do not appear in my data frame when I view it. Wouldn't happen to have any ideas would you? It almost seems to be the second collumn of coordinates causing the issue. This is perplexing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with someone much more experienced in R than I, the solution has been shown to me.

After using `dput` to see what was going on within the data, I could see a vast number of levels within the data frame that weren't present when I viewed the data itself. Some sort of hidden formatting has occurred at some point, either in the original .csv data or while I was formatting the data inside R.

The solution to this was to use `write.csv(dataframe, "filename.csv")` to create a new .csv file of just the data I had subsetted inside R. Then I read the data from this new .csv back in to R, and retried the plot using this dataframe instead, and the problem was solved.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific reason to use `rworldmap` ? otherwise [`leaflet`](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) is the best option to generate interactive map !

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```

Comment: No specific reason, other than it was initially supposed to be simple to use. The only function I need is plotting coordinate points on a map, and then overlaying some pre plotted pie charts I made. Is this still possible in leaflet? Not looking specifically for something interactive.